# My container is a flexbox, and contains 3 divs. How do I align one div to the left, one in the center, and one to the right?

Tags: css, flexbox

Basically, given a template like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-one">
  </div>
  <div class="item-two">
  </div>
  <div class="item-three">
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `class="container"` is a flexbox:

```
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

How would you align the three items like this:

`[ item-one             item-two               item-three]`

I can't use floats since I am using flexbox, and the reason I am using flexbox is because `item-two` is dynamic and may have a varying width.

Thanks

Comment: If [item-two] has variable width, as you mention, that's no big deal. You can apply `justify-content: space-between` (or `space-around`) to the container. But if  [item-one] and [item-three] are not equal width, you'll need another method. See boxes #71-78 here: [**Methods for Aligning Flex Items**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: Set the items to "flex: 1" and change the "justify-content" property on the container class to "space-between".

Comment: @cewn, if you set the items to `flex: 1`, they consume all space, and `space-between` does nothing.

Comment: Ah forgot, change flex flow to "row wrap" on the container and try "flex: 1 1 auto" on the items.